# Type 'Session' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, unknown>'

Tags: typescript

I am trying to implement the callback of https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks#session-callback. The `sesssion` callback is defined as follows:

```
export interface CallbacksOptions {
    session?:
        | ((session: Session) => WithAdditionalParams<Session>)
        | ((session: Session, userOrToken: User | JWT) => Promise<WithAdditionalParams<Session>>);
}
```

The implementation of the `session` callback:

```
   async session(session: Session, token: JWT) {

        if (token?.accessToken) {
            session.user.accessToken = token.accessToken;
            session.accessToken = token.accessToken as string;
        }

        if (token?.provider) {
            session.user.provider = token.provider;
        }

        if (token?.accountId) {
            session.user.accountId = token.accountId;
        }

        return Promise.resolve<WithAdditionalParams<Session>>(session);
    }
```

The compiler complains:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'Session' is not assignable to parameter of type 'WithAdditionalParams<Session> | PromiseLike<WithAdditionalParams<Session>>'.
  Type 'Session' is not assignable to type 'WithAdditionalParams<Session>'.
    Type 'Session' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, unknown>'.
      Index signature is missing in type 'Session'.
```

the `session` is defined as follows:

```
export interface Session {
    user: WithAdditionalParams<User>;
    accessToken?: string;
    expires: string;
}

export type WithAdditionalParams<T extends Record<string, any>> = T & Record<string, unknown>;

export interface User {
    name?: string | null;
    email?: string | null;
    image?: string | null;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
The repo of next-auth is hosted on https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth and types https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/7c785c26527720bf726f8b8bcbab2f96c600d1a4/types/next-auth/index.d.ts

Comment: The issue here is that `Session` is an interface without an index signature, and as per [microsoft/TypeScript#15300](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300), interfaces do not get "implicit index signatures".  Therefore you can't just use a `Session` where the compiler expects a `Session & Record<string, unknown>`, because the former has no index signature while the latter has one.  You can use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to make it work, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mMyprm). Does that work for you?

Comment: If that resolves your issue I'll write up an answer; if not, could you elaborate on what I'm missing?

Comment: wow..works like a charm. One more question. What is implicit index signatures?

Comment: I will talk about that when I get a chance to write up an answer, but basically the compiler will sometimes allow you to assign a type without an index signature to one with a signature by “implicitly” adding an index signature to the former type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write

```
Promise.resolve<WithAdditionalParams<Session>(session); // error!
```

you are trying to use a value of type `Session`, in a position that expects a value of type `WithAdditionalParams<Session>`.  And because the compiler does not see `Session` as assignable to `WithAdditionalParams<Session>`, there is an error.  If you tried to write

```
Promise.resolve<number>("someString"); // error! string is not a number
```

you'd have a similar error.  Presumably you would not think to use a `string` where a `number` was needed.  So the question is: why is `Session` not assignable to `WithAdditionalParams<Session>`?

---

Well, the type `WithAdditionalParams<Session>` is a *subtype* of `Session` with includes a [`string` index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) whose properties are of type `unknown`.  (This is what `Record<string, unknown>` means.)  Since `Session` does not have an index signature, the compiler does not consider `WithAdditionalParams<Session>` assignable to `Session`.

But surely, you might think, any random extra property of `session` would be assignable to the `unknown` type... *everything* is assignable to `unknown`.  So why doesn't the compiler just treat `Session` *as if* it had a string index signature?  And in fact, this sort of thing *does* happen sometimes, via [*implicit index signatures*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#implicit-index-signatures)".  Observe:

```
type SessionType = {
  user: WithAdditionalParams<User>;
  accessToken?: string;
  expires: string;
}
declare const session: SessionType;
Promise.resolve<WithAdditionalParams<Session>>(session); // no error
```

Here the value `session` is of the type `SessionType`, a [type alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-aliases) of an object type with an identical structure to `Session`.  And the compiler is perfectly happy using `SessionType` where `WithAdditionalParams<Session>` is expected... it gives `SessionType` an implicit index signature and everything succeeds.

(So, one possible way for you to deal with this is to use `SessionType` instead of `Session`.)

---

So *now* the question is, why does `Session`, an `interface`, *not* get implicit index signatures while `SessionType`, an identically-structured `type` alias, *does*?  Surely, you might again think, the compiler does not simply deny implicit index signatures to `interface` types?  Surprisingly enough, *this is exactly what happens*.

See [microsoft/TypeScript#15300](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300), specifically [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300#issuecomment-332366024):

> Just to fill people in, this behavior is currently by design. Because interfaces can be augmented by additional declarations but type aliases can't, it's "safer" (heavy quotes on that one) to infer an implicit index signature for type aliases than for interfaces. But we'll consider doing it for interfaces as well if that seems to make sense

And there you go.  You cannot use a `Session` in place of a `WithAdditionalParams<Session>` because it's possible that someone might [merge](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces) properties that conflict with the index signature at some later date.  Whether or not that is a compelling reason is up for rather vigorous debate, as you can see if you read through microsoft/TypeScript#15300.

---

So, how can we proceed?  If you do not want to change `Session` from an `interface` to a `type` alias, you can always employ the tool that tells the compiler "I don't care if you think value `x` is not of type `Y`, I'm telling you it is!"  That is, use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions):

```
Promise.resolve(session as WithAdditionalParams<Session>); // no error
```

This works because the compiler sees `session`'s type as "related" to `WithAdditionalParams<Session>`, so when you assert that it actually *is* that type, the compiler takes your word for it and moves on.  Note that once you give `session` the type `WithAdditionalParams<Session>` you don't have to manually specify the type parameter on the call to `Promise.resolve()`; the compiler infers that automatically.

Keep in mind that when you use type assertions you are taking the responsibility for verifying their accuracy upon yourself... since the compiler cannot verify it for you, it won't be able to verify that you've done the assertion correctly.  If it turns out that your assertion was incorrect, then you have lied to the compiler and any unpleasant things to happen at runtime as a result are your fault and not the compiler's.  So take care to use assertions only when you are relatively certain that it is safe to do so.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-1RyLRL4-P7AAB03IgpgAbsAWKEVJlqY0AETUH7ADpasu9CxwAD0jbIUG+UAAhL6XH8lBB4JgTMW0NE5Mo1NQwG6AJIqMCmbyjbGKMUSuCY2rEcV4Q2exS4qD40aEkFzOXkynnB2KRT07pMu5hrW0xSc7m87i0qKKSiMUxLPAmFKeB9naddoSQLcJVpVNfkqLMqhzfMAWPaVQVlMlIQ3GEWgg+smxbURW3bZM5EwahRSQbA4HQQQfFqHQINwjZ7mwpA+BgG47m0V5+nkawEHQXZOOZdQMzvRkuKQPjrAqCCMwPcTsAZagHyQQYRSkpSVLUl9GJY7T7ykjSRLuQzJOZOlaHDL9okUQThKksSwG+XMEF-KAZJvfSDgU84MxciA3I8kytMC4K0FsgShMaUy6m0iBBBgadKC8m9QJKPy0ASpKUtC5kcpQFKousfxfCgdTYPTBDKzzYBmKxci4ClIl0PBC8oRY2FkyAA)

Comment: Awesome explanation. Thanks a lot.